# How to log operations inside foldl function Haskell?

Tags: haskell

For example, I want to develop `sum` function, which will show the interim results.

My basic function is:

```
ownPlus start list = foldr (+) start list
```

I want to add `Writer Monad` inside foldl. So prototype of my function is:

```
sumWithLogging :: (Show a, Num a) => a -> [a] -> Writer String a
sumWithLogging start list = foldr ((+) do tell ["msg"]) start list
```

I have a problem with writing this function. But I want my result looks like this:

```
*Main> runWriter $ sumWithLogging 0 [1..2]
(3,"(1+(2+0))")
```

Comment: You may find it helpful to look at the source code for `mapAccumL` in `Data.Traversable`. There should be some common patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`scanl`** might be a useful function.

From Hoogle:

> scanl is similar to foldl, but returns a list of successive reduced values from the left.

So, you can see the progressive results as so:

```
λ> scanl (+) 0 [1,2,3]
[0,1,3,6]
λ> scanl (flip (:)) [] [1,2,3,4,5]
[[],[1],[2,1],[3,2,1],[4,3,2,1],[5,4,3,2,1]]
```

---

If you're wanting writer-like results, it's simple. You don't even need to use `Writer`, and avoiding use of over-complex features is always good.

```
logSum = foldl (\(n,s) x -> (n+x, "(" ++ s ++ "+" ++ show x ++ ")")) (0,"0")

λ> logSum [1..2]
(3, "((0+1)+2)")
```

I might add that `foldl` should describe *left associative operations*, but the brackets imply *right associativity* in the way that you're writing them.

If you want it to be right-associative (like the `(:)` operator), it's easy; use `foldr`:

```
 logSumR = foldr (\x (n,s) -> (x:n, show x ++ " : " ++ s)) ([],"[]")
```

So that:

```
λ logSumR [1,2,3,4,5]
([1,2,3,4,5], "1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : []")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care too much about the parentheses, the following could be a good starting point:

```
sumWithLogging :: (Show a, Num a) => a -> [a] -> Writer String a
sumWithLogging start list = foldlM step start list <* tell (show list)
    where step acc item = tell (show item ++ "+") >> return (item+acc)
```

Comment: I am sorry, but what `<*` means?

Comment: If you have two monadic computations `act1` and `act2`, then `act1 <* act2` first executes `act1`, then `act2` and finally returns the result of `act1`. So, `act1 <* act2 = act1 >>= \r -> act2 >> return r`. You can find `<*` in `Control.Applicative`.